# Difference in syntax of a function that I cannot understand

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree, traversal, breadth-first-search

I was writing a function for a Breadth first search alogrithm.  I would have come up with the following code

```
traverseBF() {
        const results = []
        const queue = [this.root]
        while (queue.length) {
            let node = queue.shift()
            if (node.children) {
                queue.push(...node.children)
            }
            results.push(node)
        }
        return results
    }
```

However, the solution was written somewhat differently as

```
traverseBF(fn) {
        const queue = [this.root]
        while (queue.length) {
            let node = queue.shift()
            if (node.children) {
                queue.push(...node.children)
            }
            fn(node)
        }
    }
```

I cannot explain what `fn(node)` purpose is or how it returns the correct result.  Is this some kind of recursive call?  How are the two solutions different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning results like you are, they're allowing the user to pass in a function that gets passed each node as it's traversed.

Try for example:

```
obj.traverseBF(node => console.log(node))
```

Or just

```
obj.traverseBF(console.log)
```

Should work as well. `console.log` is given each node to use as it's found.

This is arguably more general purpose. If the tree was large, accumulating all the results in a list may waste memory if the user doesn't need all the results at once.

If the user wanted to accumulate a list though, they could pass in a function that appends to a list that the function closes over:

```
nodes = [];
obj.traverseBF(node => nodes.push(node))

console.log(nodes)
```